# Python : declaring matrix using rgbmatrix.so loads cpu when using time.sleep

Tags: python, cpu-load

This is my first post here, so all my apologies if I missed a specific rule of the site.

Here is my point :
I have a 16x32 Adafruit Matrix with the Hat for Rpi. The hardware part went with no particular issue.I installed the python and software libraries as described in the documentation. I could also run the demos and even control my matrix (display image, scrolling text, both etc...).
But I noticed that -when I run a python matrix related program- my RPi3 CPU load is 100% on one CPU which finally leads to system crash after a while.

I did some extensive tests to understand when this does occur, and here is my conclusion : declaring a matrix with the adafruit library loads the processor when I try to use the time.sleep(n) function.

I am not familiar with libraries compilation, but I cannot figure out why just declaring a variable would generate loading issue.

Here is my demo code :

```
#!/usr/bin/python             # This is server.py file
# This Python file uses the following encoding: utf-8

import time
from rgbmatrix import Adafruit_RGBmatrix

matrix = Adafruit_RGBmatrix(16, 1)

while True:
   time.sleep(10)
```

The library used can be found here :
[rgbmatrix.cc](https://github.com/adafruit/rpi-rgb-led-matrix/blob/master/rgbmatrix.cc)

I understand my question is specific to a trademark but they did not give me any answer on their forum, so I hope a good dev will be able to help me find out what happens, as the time.sleep function is suppose to hold the execution instead of generating a 100% load.

EDIT : This is a bug from Adafruit library... I compiled directly Hzeller led library and the problem was gone.

Comment: Welcome to the stackoverflow! Good you solved your problem. BTW, it's ok to answer and accept your own question. That's better that editing your question. That way if other people have the same problem they may find this and see inmediatly it has an answer.